# requestFiltering has Invalid Child element <alwaysAllowedUrls>

Tags: .net, xml, configuration, web-config, requestfiltering

I want to block xml files to have direct access by urls but want to give access to only one URL with xml extension.
Tried this code from microsoft and done some modifications.

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <fileExtensions>
            <add fileExtension=".xml" allowed="false"/>
         </fileExtensions>
         <alwaysAllowedUrls>
            <add url="/bad_sequence.txt" />
         </alwaysAllowedUrls>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

visual studio showing  is invalid child.
my IIS is 10.version.

Comment: also All the tags added from iis 7.5 are not seen

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and installing visual studio 2019 latest version seemed to address the problem.  Ref - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/webconfig-schema-does-not-recognize-removeserverhe/292146